# Calendar Overlay question

Tags: calendar

I asked this same question on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7448582/282110), then I found this stackexchange site. I'm hoping for better results.

I have a sharepoint 2010 PTO calendar that has multiple views, approved PTO and pending PTO. Approved PTO view is set as the default view for the calendar and Pending PTO is set as a calendar overlay on the approved PTO view.

If I double click an Approved PTO item, the edit form comes up in a silverlight window on the same IE window. But, when I double click a Pending PTO (non-default view) item, that edit form for the item opens in a new IE window.

Is there any way to have a non default view item open in the silverlight window?

Comment: a silverlight window, really?

Comment: I associate SP making me install silverlight when I first tried creating a list with all the popups that happen during different events. Please explain if I'm wrong.

Comment: Typically I call that a lightbox style window

Comment: I see. SharePoint relies on Silverlight (optional) in the list creation process. But the overlays you get when you view or edit an item (and a single click should be enough) are just html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately for the items that come in through the overlay, it could be from anywhere and therefor they cannot treat the data the same way so the functionality is different.